# Returning the correct type in C# linq query over DataRows

Tags: c#, linq

I can't seem to get the following working

```
var results = (from DataRow row in myDataView.Table.Rows
                    group row by row["part"] into x
                    select new {x}).Distinct();

foreach(var x in results)
 {
 doSomething(x["part"]);
 doSomethingElse(x["field2"]);
 }
```

The problem seems to be that results contains elements of "AnonymousType" which I guess is an artifact of "group". How can I make the above code work as I expect?

Comment: And how do you expect it to work?

Comment: For results to return DataRow objects. Or at least some way to easily access the fields of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new {x}
```

this will create an anonimous type with property 'x' where x object will be stored. This is short syntax for:

```
new {x = x} // first x is property name
```

in your case you should simply select x:

```
var results = (from DataRow row in myDataView.Table.Rows
                    group row by row["part"] into x
                    select x).Distinct();
```

Also Distinct() after Group looks strange. What did you mean?

Comment: I want to return the unique combinations of two fields that occur in the table. I used distinct but I actually want to "group" by two columns

Comment: Here I see only one field - 'part', where do you think to use the other field? Anyway in such order Distinct() won't filter anything since grouped values are always distinct.

Comment: maybe you should try this: (from DataRow row in myDataView.Table.Rows select new {Part=row["part"], Field2=row["field2"]}).Distinct()